# Sharepoint Display Templates How to use Group Display Template

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, display-templates

the code in the control display template uses `_#= ctx.RenderGroups(ctx) =#_` and there is another JS file named `group_content.js` that is being called, how do i split my data into groups in order to render some HTML per group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After intensive research, you need to do some manually to use it.

1. Create Group Display Template file, just take the default "group_xxx.html" from the "Search" or "Content Search" Folders, whatever you are using.
2. MUST download a copy or you Search WebPart (export) and change the value in "GroupTemplateId" to your group JS file.
3. CODING objects to mimic `ResultTables` object

final code

```
ctx.ClientControl.set_groupTemplateId('~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/display templates/content web parts/Group_Content_QA.js');
ctx.ListDataJSONGroupsKey = "ResultGrouped"
ctx.ListData.ResultGrouped = [];

//function to create the ResultTables fake array
function createResultGroup(items){
 return {
  ResultRows: items, 
  RowCount: items.length,
  TableType: "RelevantResults",
 }
};

//just a ref
var _items = ctx.ListData.ResultTables[0].ResultRows;

//categories dictionary
var _groupDictionary = {};

//populating dictionary categories
_items.forEach(function(e) {
    if ( !_groupDictionary[e.QACategoryOWSCHCS] ){
   _groupDictionary[e.QACategoryOWSCHCS] = [];
    }
});

//populating dictionary categories with items
_items.forEach(function(e) {
 _groupDictionary[e.QACategoryOWSCHCS].push(e);
});

//adding to ctx categories as a named array
ctx.groupsNames = Object.keys(_groupDictionary);

//populating fake ResultTables array (ResultGrouped)
ctx.groupsNames.forEach(function(g) {
 ctx.ListData.ResultGrouped.push(
  createResultGroup(_groupDictionary[g])
 );
});
```

[read more here](http://bresleveloper.blogspot.co.il/2017/12/sharepoint-group-display-templates.html)

Answer (score 0):

As completing your answer, I think the beauty of using `ctx.ListData[ctx.ListDataJSONGroupsKey]` array is using different group and item display templates for each Group. Watching this array using developer tools shows an array of objects in the following form:

```
GroupTemplateId: null
ItemTemplateId: null
Properties: {GenerationId: 9223372036854776000, indexSystem: "", ExecutionTimeMs: 63, QueryModification: "path:"https://modernsharepointexperiences.sharepoi…tItem") -ContentClass=urn:content-class:SPSPeople", RenderTemplateId: "~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/Display Templates/Search/Group_Default.js", …}
QueryId: "ca540784-162f-4a9e-9ad4-da45e615ca06"
QueryRuleId: "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
ResultRows: (10) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
ResultTitle: null
ResultTitleUrl: null
RowCount: 10
TableType: "RelevantResults"
TotalRows: 10
TotalRowsIncludingDuplicates: 31
_ObjectType_: "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Search.Query.ResultTable"
```

Here, I think, we can set Group Display Template and Item Display Template for each element of above array (really each group). Please correct me if you think I am wrong! Thanks